# Python AWS CDK build broke yesterday - 'Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.'

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, libxml2, aws-lambda-layers, libxslt

I've been using CDK to regularly deploy my python-based lambdas to AWS for over a year and it's been working great. The build broke yesterday, and I noticed that the image I'm using was updated a couple of days ago: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/commits/python3.9/Dockerfile.python3.9

I'm now getting a build error 'Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.'

My functions and layers are build in a similar fashion, e.g.:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_lambda_python_alpha as _lambda,
    DockerImage,
    AssetHashType,
    NestedStack,
    RemovalPolicy,
)


def create_lambda_layer(
    self, deploy_folder: str, layer_name: str, only_include_these=[]
) -> _lambda.PythonLayerVersion:
    layer_folder = self.build_dependencies_layer(
        deploy_folder, layer_name, only_include_these=only_include_these
    )
    print(layer_name, layer_folder, deploy_folder, only_include_these)
    return _lambda.PythonLayerVersion(
        self,
        layer_name,
        entry=layer_folder,
        compatible_runtimes=[Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
        compatible_architectures=[Architecture.ARM_64],
        bundling={
            "image": DockerImage("public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9:latest-arm64"),
            "asset_hash_type": AssetHashType.SOURCE,
        },
        removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
    )
```

I have a particular layer which depends on the Zeep python library. I recall this being problematic to bundle/build on my Apple Silicon Mac. When building that layer, pip running within a Docker image fails with the following error:

```
Collecting lxml>=4.6.0
  Downloading lxml-4.9.3.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.6/3.6 MB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.3.
      Building without Cython.
      Error: Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

The salient line from that is:

```
Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.
```

How do I make these available to the docker images doing the build? Do I build my own image, or do I need to run some install steps 'on'/'in' the docker image. Any suggestions?

[edit]
I tried modifying the build to point at a Docker file and install the dependencies myself. I can see these binaries being installed in the Docker image, but pip within the container still failes

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9:latest-arm64
RUN yum install -y libxml2 libxslt
```

[/edit]

[edit2]
Got it working. I was yum installing libxml2 and libxslt, and not their DEVELOPMENT packages, which was what the build error said. So this was resolved by doing this in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9:latest-arm64
RUN yum install -y Cython libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```

and then for building the layer I now do:

```
bundling={
  'image': DockerImage.from_build(os.path.expanduser('~/workplace/cdk/stacks/')),
  'asset_hash_type': AssetHashType.SOURCE
}
```

and it's working

[/edit2]

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I was yum installing libxml2 and libxslt, and not their DEVELOPMENT packages, which was what the build error said. So this was resolved by doing this in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9:latest-arm64
RUN yum install -y Cython libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```

and then for building the layer I now do:

```
bundling={
  'image': DockerImage.from_build(os.path.expanduser('~/workplace/cdk/stacks/')),
  'asset_hash_type': AssetHashType.SOURCE
}
```

and it's working